# when I create a new page with \pagebreak all the content of the page is extended

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

I'm using a latex template and, when I try to create a section in another page, for instance:
[image]

All the text goes like this one:

[image]

Comment: use \newpage or use \raggedbottom.

Comment: thank you! using \raggedbottom and \sectionbreak{\clearpage} worked for me